# The memory returned by realloc is filled with random characters. Is this expected?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am using realloc to expand the initial memory I have declared for a dynamically allocated array. I do not know the dimension of the input so i read it character by character, and when I detect that I exceed the memory that has initially been allocated I call realloc. Here is the Code:

```
void readLine(char *line, int &len) {
    int newSize = expand;
    char ch;
    while(f >> noskipws >> ch) {
        if (ch == '\n')
            break;
        if (++len >= newSize - 1) {
            newSize += expand;
            line = (char*)realloc(line, newSize);
        }
        line[len] = ch;
    }
}
```

My problem is that after the program reallocs 'line' it fills it with various ASCII characters. Is this a normal behaviour?

Comment: Why don't you use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)?

Comment: just a thought, since we're using c++ can't we just `push_back` the character into a std::string or std::vector<char>??

Comment: You also have other major problems with that function, like not terminating the string, not handling `realloc` returning `NULL`  and worst of all you modify an argument that is passed by value.

Comment: Using plain C. I wish I could use c++... @RichardHodges

Comment: Uhm, but you *are* using C++! What do you thing that right-shift operator would do in C? What do you think `noskipws` would do in C? How would passing an argument by reference work in C? That code is most definitely C++. Removing the C++ tag won't make the code less C++.

Comment: @AndreiDiaconu the question is tagged c++

Comment: Yes it is C++ but i use C for memory management. @JoachimPileborg

Comment: How can this work anyway?  a realloc for 'line', a local parameter, will not propagate outside the function.

Comment: Yes it will @MartinJames.

Comment: IMO that's just stupid. You have facilities that will handle everything for you automatically, why won't you use them? Your function can't even be called from a C program because you pass an argument by reference, which doesn't exist in C, and even if it could you could still use `std::getline` and `std::string` inside the function.

Comment: @AndreiDiaconu how?   You don't return it?

Comment: Regarding the `realloc` issue pointed out by @MartinJames, I suggest you check the pointer returned by `realloc` and compare it with the pointer you pass to `realloc` (in a debugger or by printing out the pointers). I can almost certainly bet it will be different each time you call `realloc`.

Comment: Although `realloc()` is *permitted* to extend the block passed to it, that depends on there being space available to do so, which is uncommon.  Typically it allocates a new, larger block, copies the data from the old block, and frees the old block, making the original pointer invalid.

Comment: That's what I thought.  It would be safe if the function returned 'line' so that the caller could reseat it's own pointer.

Comment: This is C++. It is invalid code in C.

Comment: Note also that the copying behavior associated with `realloc()` has an associated cost that can easily be overlooked.  If you use `realloc()` naively or carelessly then you can end up with code that scales more poorly than it should do.

Comment: "Yes it will @MartinJames" Sounds like kindergarten. Please explain how it will!

Comment: `while(f >> noskipws >> ch)` makes little sense in C.  Post code that compiles.

Comment: @chux: While that is still syntactical correct and might just throw warnings (too lazy to check), the function declarator is clearly invalid.

Answer (score 3):

> after the program `realloc`s `line` it fills it with various ASCII characters.

`realloc` does not fill the memory that it returns back with anything. This random garbage is a leftover from whatever was using the memory before. Your code is not supposed to read any of the allocated bytes without writing something into it.

The reason you may see this random data is that your `line` is left unterminated. Add `line[++len] = '\0';` after the loop to fix this problem.

An even bigger problem with your code is that `line` is a pointer passed to your function by value. This means that any re-assignments that you make will not be propagated to the caller. Moreover, if the caller passed you valid memory and you called `realloc` on it, the pointer in the caller would be invalidated on successful `realloc`.

To fix this problem pass `line` as a reference to pointer:

```
void readLine(char*& line, int &len) {
    ...
}
```

**Note:** I assume that you are doing this as an exercise in using `realloc`, because C++ Standard Library has built-in functionality for reading `std::string`s of arbitrary size.

Another important point is that you should not assign `realloc` to `line` right away. Instead, you should assign it to a temporary variable, check for `NULL`, and assign to `line` only if it passes the check. This would let you avoid memory leaks in situations when the system runs out of memory.

Comment: Can you explain how the function can work?  realloc can modify line, but only a local copy...  Surely, this leaves the caller with a duff 'line' pointer?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Martin's comment came before the edit, though.

Comment: @MartinJames You are right, I looked straight at `realloc` call, completely missing the way the OP passes `line` into his function. Thank you!

Comment: No probs, I just wanted to be sure I had it right:)